# Setting device profile on PipeWire

Tags: audio, arch-linux, pulse-audio, pipewire

I have a gaming headset with both chat and game outputs, but I can only select Digital Output + Mono Input in audio settings.

Back in Manjaro with PulseAudio I added a udev rule like

```
echo 'ATTRS{idVendor}=="3329", ATTRS{idProduct}=="4b19", ENV{PULSE_PROFILE_SET}="usb-gaming-headset.conf"' | sudo tee -a /etc/udev/rules.d/91-pulseaudio-audeze-gamedac.rules > /dev/null
```

How to do this with pipewire?